# How to split column into two columns based on unique ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two IDs and I want to split those values into two different columns
Here is the example
I want to have one column name Cash for cash values and one column for Card values

```
id  type    value
1   cash     1000 
2   card     3500 
2   card     1600 
1   cash     500 
1   cash     300
```

Don't have any query because I don't know where to start from.

Expected results should be

```
id   card   cash
2    3500   null 
1    null   1000
2    1600   null
1    null   500
1    null   300
```

Comment: search for `PIVOT`

Comment: So what is your question? What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work? What are you expected results for the above?

Comment: And your SQL code is where?

Comment: I'm not even sure the OP needs a `PIVOT`/conditional aggregate, @Squirrel . Depends what the expected results are.

Comment: I do not have SQL code because I really do not know where to start from on this one..

Comment: If you really don't know where to start, then probably your want a tutorial to get your SQL to a level where you can start to solve these problems. You'll learn a lot more that way than if someone just does it for you. I suspect you want to check out a `case` expression.

Comment: You're trying to add two extra columns, one that has a value only if `type` is `card` and another only if `type` is `cash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `case` expressions:

```
select id,
       (case when type = 'card' then value end) as card,
       (case when type = 'cash' then value end) as cash
from t;
```

Note:  The ordering for the result set is indeterminate.  You have not explained if the ordering is important to the question, but you seem to have the highest value for each id, then the second highest, and so on.  If that is really desired:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc),
         id desc
```